# AesManaged implementation breaks under Mono...?

Tags: c#, encryption, mono, cryptography

I've got a program that under Windows and .NET Framework 4 works perfectly well however, under Mono (built in MonoDevelop 2.6), the `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()` function seem to only half work...

To the point at which if I locally encrypt something and then immediately decrypt it (under Mono), the first 10 or so characters of the message are scrambled jiberish, but anything following looks perfectly valid!

The Encrypt function is as follows:

```
    public byte[] Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string timeStamp = now.Millisecond.ToString("000") + "." + now.Second.ToString("00") + "." +
            now.Minute.ToString("00") + "." + now.Hour.ToString("00") + Constants.MessageSplitChar;
        plainText = plainText.Insert(0, timeStamp);

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        lock (this.encryptor)
        {
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, this.encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
            try
            {
                writer.Write(plainText);
            }
            finally
            {
                writer.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();
                memoryStream.Close();
            }
        }

        byte[] encryptedMessage = memoryStream.ToArray();
        return this.AppendArrays(BitConverter.GetBytes(encryptedMessage.Length), encryptedMessage);
    }
```

The Decrypt function is as follows:

```
    public string Decrypt(byte[] cipherText)
    {
        try
        {
            string plainText = string.Empty;

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherText);

            lock (this.decryptor)
            {
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, this.decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);

                try
                {
                    plainText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    plainText = plainText.Substring(plainText.IndexOf("|") + 1);
                    plainText = plainText.TrimEnd("\0".ToCharArray());
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.Close();
                    cryptoStream.Close();
                    memoryStream.Close();
                }
            }

            return plainText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CMicroBingoServer.LogManager.Write(ex.ToString(), MessagePriority.Error);
            return "DECRYPTION_FAILED";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not show how your `decryptor` and `encryptor` instances are created.

This can be a problem because **if** you're reusing the instance then you must check `ICryptoTransform.CanReuseTransform`. If it returns **false** then you cannot reuse the same encryptor/decryptor and must create new instances.

That's even more important since Mono and .NET have different defaults for some algorithms. But in any case skipping this check means that any changes in future .NET framework (or via configuration files, since cryptography is pluggable using `CryptoConfig`) is likely to break your code someday.

Comment: Bingo, well said that man! I hadn't even realised that I needed to check that I could reuse the encryption / decryption interface! Any idea why you need to do this? (albeit just to satisfy my curiosity!)

Answer (score 3):

It may be important how many <del>characters</del> bytes at the beginning are seemingly gibberish... If the first block is coming out nonsense but the rest is fine then it could be that your initialization vector is not correct on decryption.

Under the most common block mode, CBC, when decrypting the IV only effects teh decryption of the first block of data since after that its the cipher text that acts as the IV for later blocks.

Are you explicitly setting IVs for encrypting and decrypting? If not then I would imagine that the two have different behaviours when dealing with unset IVs (eg windows uses all zeros and mono generates a random IV - this would cause windows to decrypt fine becuase the IV is the same whereas mono may be generating two different IVs for the encrypt and decrypt process.

I don't know mono stuff well enough to look into the exact solution but something along these lines seems likely.

Comment: Not a bad idea.. I'll take a look at the IVs and see if I can spot anything going a bit awry.